# Why are these angles equal for object on inclined plane?

Tags: geometry, physics

This is a common setup for kinematics problems in physics. My geometry is rusty and I want to understand this very simple idea.

[image]

I am having trouble understanding why the angle $\theta$ formed by $\overrightarrow{w}$ is equal to $\theta$ = $\angle$ BOA.

My initial ideas:

- If we extend $w$ we can get a right triangle and somehow prove the angles equal by similarity.
- Some sort of use of interior angles and parallel lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is essentially the same as the one given by half-integer fan, but I'll add a picture in case it will aid your understanding. I have labeled new points $C$ and $D$ so that I can refer to them.

[image]

$\triangle OCD$ is a right triangle, as is $\triangle OCE$. Because $$\angle OCD=90^\circ=\angle OCE+\angle DCE=\angle OCE+\alpha$$
and
$$\angle OCE+\angle COE+90^\circ=\angle OCE+\theta+90^\circ=180^\circ$$
we have that
$$\angle OCE +\theta=90^\circ\quad \text{ and }\quad \angle OCE+\alpha=90^\circ,$$
so we must have $\theta=\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although it seems that you did not use the same method as half-integer fan. His used the similar triangle `△BOA` (from original image) and `△COE` (from your image). Am I correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Since $w \parallel AB$ it follows that

$$\theta + 90^\circ+ \angle B =180^\circ \,.$$

Now, use that $\angle B= 90^\circ- \theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct.  If you extend $W$ downward to make a right triangle, the angle opposite to $\angle BOA$ will be $90 - \angle BOA$.  Since the angle between the parallel and normal components of $W$ is also $90$, that means $\theta = 90 - (90- \angle BOA) = \angle BOA$.

Answer (score 2):

Not rigorous by any means, but notice that the two angles open at the same rate.

[image: triangle animation]

Answer (score 0):

As @Zev Chonels said

∠OCD = 90∘ = ∠OCE + α

therefore ∠OCE = 90 - α

and

∠OCE + θ + 90∘ = 180∘    (sums of all angle of triangle = 180∘)

substitute the value of ∠OCE

90∘ - α + θ + 90∘ = 180∘

θ - α + 180∘ = 180∘

θ - α = 180∘ - 180∘

θ - α = 0

θ = α

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).